# Is it feasible to store a sqlite DB containing 333,000 rows locally on an iPhone/iPod Touch?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, sqlite, core-data

I have a huge table, which has 3 columns and about 333,000 rows. The sql dump is about 58 MB, and the sqlite DB containing this one table is about 20 MB.

I want to implement a sort of "autocomplete" where the user types into a `UISearchBar` and a `UITableView` gets updated. I have it working where every time the user types a letter it makes an HTTPrequest, but there's a very noticeable lag between the time the user types a letter and the UITableView gets updated. I was thinking storing the DB locally would speed things up, but, it's a **very** large DB.

Is it feasible to store that large of a DB on a device? Would using Core Data be a better option?

Comment: It'll be that large no matter which you use; just make sure your queries and indexes are very well optimized. A DB guru can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CoreData will end up using sqlite, so if you manage your memory correctly, and depending on how many records you handle at 1 time, you should be Ok.

Answer (score 0):

Seems reasonable to me.  I'd just go for it!

Comment: I've seen a few references to there being a size limit of 20 MB to be able to download the app. Is that accurate, and on apple's docs somewhere? If that's the case it may not be feasible to include the DB initially.

Comment: I think it's 2GB http://www.intomobile.com/2008/06/12/apple-setting-iphone-application-size-and-price-limits-for-appstore/

Comment: @moshe the 20MB limit refers to download over cell connection, more than that and the app has to be downloaded over wifi.

Comment: Thanks, my app may indeed be larger than 20MB. I may have to load part of the DB after the app is launched for the first time or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to also look into TokyoCabinet. It might be better suited for your requirements. If it is, you should look at the BNRPersistence code to help manage the data: https://github.com/hillegass/BNRPersistence